# proving a property of elements under homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

I am trying to prove that  φ(a) =  φ(b) if and only if a*Ker (φ) = b * Ker( φ).

This is what I have so far:

> φ(b)^(-1) φ(b)^(-1) φ(a)(b)= φ(b)^(-1) φ(a)
>   e' = φ(b)^(-1) φ(a)
>   e' = φ(b^-1) φ(a)
>   therefore (b^(-1) * a) is an element of the kernal
>   and b* kerφ = a* kerφ

and going in the other direction I have

> a* kerφ = b* kerφ
>   ae' = be'
>   φ(a)=φ(b)

Will this proof work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think it will.

Let's start with part (2):

let's call $\text{ker }\phi, K$.

So, given $aK = bK$, we know that $a = ae = bk$, for some $k \in K$.

Thus $\phi(a) = \phi(bk) = \phi(b)\phi(k)$, since $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

Given that $\phi(k) = e'$ (since $k \in \text{ker }\phi$), what are your conclusions?

The first part is a bit better, but it should start like this:

$\phi(a) = \phi(b) \implies [\phi(b)]^{-1}\phi(a) = e'$

Your first statement is a bit muddled, and has too many instances of $\phi(b)^{-1}$.